# Abort operation handling

Tags: beacon

I am trying to setup a Tezos wallet connectivity using Beacon sdk dappclient. I am adding custom handler on abort for wallt connectivity but for some reason it is not working for custom logic and still falling back to default behaviour. I am following this from the docs:
https://docs.walletbeacon.io/advanced/ui-elements

```
const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true); // Start loading

      const handlePermissionRequestError = (error: any) => {
        console.log("Signing request error:", error);
        setLoading(false); // Reset the loading state
      };

      const handlePairInit = async (eventData: {
        p2pPeerInfo: () => Promise<P2PPairingRequest>;
        postmessagePeerInfo: () => Promise<PostMessagePairingRequest>;
        walletConnectPeerInfo: () => Promise<WalletConnectPairingRequest>;
        networkType: NetworkType;
        abortedHandler?(): void;
        disclaimerText?: string;
        analytics: AnalyticsInterface;
        featuredWallets?: string[];
      }): Promise<void> => {
        // If you want to attach your own "on alert closed" handler
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
        const oldHandler = eventData.abortedHandler;
        const newHandler = async (): Promise<void> => {
          if (oldHandler) {
            // Make sure to call the internal abortedHandler
            oldHandler();
          }
          // Add your own logic here
          console.log("Pairing process aborted");
          setLoading(false); // Reset the loading state

          eventData.abortedHandler = newHandler; // Replace the internal abortedHandler with the new one
          // await defaultEventCallbacks.PAIR_INIT(eventData); // Add this if you want to keep the default behaviour.
          console.log("syncInfo", eventData);
        };
      };

      dAppClient?.subscribeToEvent(BeaconEvent.PAIR_INIT, handlePairInit);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've asked the beacon team to look at this, but still no response. You could try opening an issue for them directly on their github: https://github.com/airgap-it/beacon-sdk/issues